# subtract a value from a list to each correct column dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have the following dataframe called `diamonds`.

```
  X carat       cut color clarity depth table price     x     y    z
 26450  1.53     Ideal     G    VVS1  61.8  55.0 15992  7.43  7.45 4.59
 27696  0.40     Ideal     G     SI2  62.1  57.0   648  4.72  4.75 2.94
  3596  0.90      Good     J     VS2  62.3  64.0  3423  6.09  6.17 3.82
 45732  0.70      Good     I     SI2  63.4  59.0  1699  5.66  5.57 3.56
 25894  1.50 Very Good     F     VS1  61.6  58.0 15022  7.35  7.43 4.55
  4169  1.04     Ideal     I     SI2  61.9  56.0  3553  6.51  6.45 4.02
  7721  0.26     Ideal     F     VS1  60.9  57.0   580  4.13  4.11 2.51
   202  0.70   Premium     E     SI1  61.3  58.0  2777  5.71  5.68 3.49
  8730  0.27      Good     E    VVS1  63.9  57.0   586  4.07  4.10 2.61
 20109  1.50     Ideal     G     SI2  61.4  56.0  8580  7.34  7.38 4.52
```

I create 2 new data frames based on my diamonds data frame, one will have 70% of the data called `train` and the other will have the other 30% of the data, `test` data frame.

With the following two functions I obtain a list of column means and variances from"train" dataframe.

```
meanTrain <- lapply(train[,nums],mean)
varianceTrain<- lapply(train[,nums],sd)
```

Now what I have to do is to normalize my `test` data frame.

To do it , I have to subtract to all the numeric columns from `test` data frame ( to select numeric columns --> test[,nums] )

the mean from my `train` data frame and divide it by `train` data frame variance.

I have been thinking about it, and here is my code.

```
escaladeTest <- apply(test[, nums], 2, function (col) (col - meanTrain[col])/varianceTrain[col])
```

It's not working correctly, but it's an idea of how to each one `test` data frame column, it has to being subtracted and divided by mean and variance  "train" data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing what you described, I think the following is one way to achieve your goal. You want to work on numeric columns. So your choice would be `mutate_at()` with `is.numeric`. For each numeric column, you want to subtract the mean value of the column having an identical column name in `diamonds1`. Then, you want to divide the values with sd of the same column in `diamonds1`.

`.` is basically the columns which has TRUE in `is.numeric`. If there are five columns meeting the logical condition, `.` is filled with each of the columns. For example, if `.` indicates `carat`, all `.`s indicate carat in one round. Then, `.` indicates another column and repeating the exact the same calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# I created two data sets from the diamonds data set in ggplot2
diamonds1 <- diamonds[1:10000, ]
diamonds2 <- diamonds[10001:15000, ]


mutate_if(diamonds2, is.numeric,
          funs((. - mean(diamonds1$., na.rm = T)) / sd(diamonds1$.)))

   carat cut       color clarity  depth   table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.664 Fair      D     SI1      2.45  -1.63    1.17 0.390 0.333 0.963
 2 0.707 Very Good H     SI1      0.751  0.502   1.17 0.543 0.691 0.794
 3 0.793 Good      H     SI1     -1.56  -0.777   1.17 0.896 1.05  0.528
 4 1.61  Fair      F     SI2      1.91  -0.777   1.17 1.11  1.27  1.66 
 5 0.277 Ideal     E     SI1     -0.525 -0.351   1.17 0.436 0.520 0.334
 6 0.707 Premium   E     VS2     -0.646  0.0755  1.17 0.681 0.645 0.479
 7 0.234 Very Good E     VS2     -0.889  0.928   1.17 0.374 0.473 0.189
 8 0.234 Very Good E     VS2      0.204 -0.777   1.17 0.206 0.286 0.286
 9 0.234 Very Good E     VS2      0.690  0.0755  1.17 0.221 0.270 0.407
10 0.707 Very Good G     SI1      0.326  0.928   1.17 0.543 0.629 0.648
```

Comment: @fiticida Pleasure to help.